# CakePHP: calling other Model functions

Tags: cakephp

How can i call, from a Model, a function present in another model? I would like not to repeat code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use one model inside of a different model in CakePHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/can-i-use-one-model-inside-of-a-different-model-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can use Model relation to call the function in another model. Eg.

```
$this->Model->ModelOne->find();
$this->Model->ModelOne->customFunc();
```

If there is no relation in the models, The we can use

```
$this->loadModel('ModelName');
```

To use in the model.
In this case you can use

```
$this->ModelName->function();
```

directly as you've loaded that model.

Comment: Not sure using 'loadModel' is correct as of Cake 1.3, per [The loadModel function comes handy when you need to use a model which is not the controller's default model or its associated model.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/992/loadModel). To load a Model from a Model use [ClassRegistry::init](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/class-registry#method-ClassRegistryinit)

Comment: This does not work in cakephp 2.3 ( if loaded in a controller, ofc works, in model not )

Answer (score 7):

You should try to have relationships between your models. There are many types of relationships  which you can read [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together)...

If you have above said associations, you can access your associated models using:

```
$this->Model->OtherModel->function();
```

If your models are not related in any way, you should use:

```
ClassRegistry::init('OtherModel')->function();
```

You can check out [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887257/why-is-uses-considered-bad-practice-in-cakephp) on this where I obtained great answers

Comment: ClassRegistry::init('OtherModel')->function(); Worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

User App::import()

```
App::import('Model','OtherModel');
$attr = new OtherModel();
$attr->Othermodelfunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

- if there's a (direct or indirect) relationship between the model, you can call the function: $this->Model1->Model2->...->Modeln->function();
- use bindModel

Answer (score 0):

no, you should use ClassRegistry like so:

```
    //MessagesController - in my send() method...

$this->set('content', ClassRegistry::init('Content')->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Content.id' => 3)

        )));
```

NOTE:this is from my controller but I am pretty sure it works in model too.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.x versions the `$this->Model1->Model2` syntax answered above will not work. Calling functions from another models in many cases is the job of a controller, not the model. Consider that, the model methods should be limited to querying and updating data whilst maintaining database integrity.

**1st method: using the controller**

I'll illustrate this with an example of `Firm` and `User` models, while `Firm` `hasMany` users. This method is recommended, if you plan to add extra controller functionality inbetween, such as setting flash messages or cookies.

`User` model:

```
public function saveRegisteredUsers($user_data,$firm_id){ ... }
```

--

`FirmsController`:

```
public function add(){
    if($this->Firm->save($this->request->data)){

    // set $this->Firm->id here 

    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->User->saveRegisteredUsers($this->request->data['User'], 
      $this->Firm->id);

    // ... 

    }
}
```

**2nd method: using the model**

For this you will need to have correct model associations. The table names have to be `users` and `firms` conventionally. Following the terminology of the example above your relation should be defined as this in the `Firm` model:

```
public $hasMany = array( 'User' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
));
```

In the `User` model, you have to set up the `belongsTo` association properly:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Firm' => array(
        'className' => 'Firm',
        'foreignKey' => 'firm_id',
        'dependent' => false
        )
    );
```

After this, you can call `$this->User->saveRegisteredUsers()` directly from any of the `Firm` model methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model function that you want to call from many models, the best approach is to abstract any references to the model name ($this->alias) and place the function in AppModel.  Then it is accessible in any of your models.

```
class AppModel extends Model{
    public function myFunction($options = array(){
       do some stuff with $this->alias;
    }
}
```