# PHP - Zend Framework: a model within a model?

Tags: php

I'm just wondering, I'm not an expert on MVC but have been shifting our code towards a better MVC structure on the Zend Framework over the past few years. I basically have different models handling different sets of logic for different entities in the database. For example, a Product model, and a Customer model, etc.

Is it OK for my Product model to instatiate a Customer model, so that it can use some of the Customer functions? 
OR is this the job of a controller, to call the relevant functions of Customer, and pass the results to the Product?
Let's say the Product needs to know if a Customer has certain records within it, so that the Product can decide on the correct data to return to the controller.

I am just curious on the 'best way'. I would want to instatiate a "model within a model" since the logic is needed from different controllers which call the same Product model function.

Many thanks!

Comment: Controllers are supposed to be extremely lightweight, they're just there to hand data to the model (which in reality should be a collection of interacting classes) and collect the results.  The models should know how your application works, the controllers don't need to know

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is OK to instantiate a "model within a model" as shown in case of CakePHP here:

[CakePHP: calling other Model functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204591/cakephp-calling-other-model-functions)

You may also check these links [One](http://mattmccormick.ca/2010/04/24/how-to-easily-create-models-and-table-relationships-in-zend-framework/), [Two](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html/) and [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638622/modeling-objects-with-multiple-table-relationships-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score -2):

You use bellow code

```
$product  = new Application_Model_Product();  // create model class object, any model name which you want to user 
$product->getProductList();  // just any function from model
```